# Не импортируются кавычки в SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Использую SQLiteStudio (3.1.0) для подготовки БД. 
Имеется большой набор данных в CSV файле вида:

```
число \ какой "то" текст \ какой то "текст"
```

Все это дело в `UTF-8`. Символ `"\"` в качестве разделителя.

Все бы хорошо, но при импорте в базу данных SQLiteStudio вырезает начисто все кавычки. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как импортировать текст сохраняя кавычки?

Comment: Попробуйте так \"то\"

Comment: @jisecayeyo тоже думал об этом. Но нет, не выходит.

Comment: В общем, я все таки добавил кавычки. Но, средствами `SQLiteStudio` этого сделать не вышло. За то прекрасно справился `SQLite Manager`.